# Send seek command to running ffmpeg instance

Tags: windows, ffmpeg, console, seek

I have created a video player using the ffmpeg libraries, but want to know if the same is possible using ffmpeg.exe and piping, specifically the seeking part. Is it possible to send seek command to a running ffmpeg.exe instance? Such a command is not present in the help but it does show the 'c' command which can be used to send commands to filters. I cannot find any further documentation however on how to address filters this way, all examples assuming command line parameters, nor if a filter can be used to seek in video.

Comment: Any solution yet?

Comment: @Harry nope....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually a seek command is *kind of* documented in the [ffmpeg documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffplay-all.html#Commands-67):

> Both `movie` and `amovie` support the following commands:
>
> - `seek` Perform seek using "av_seek_frame". The syntax is: `seek stream_index|timestamp|flags`
>
>   - `stream_index`: If stream_index is -1, a default stream is selected, and timestamp is automatically converted from AV_TIME_BASE units to the stream specific time_base.
>   - `timestamp`: Timestamp in AVStream.time_base units or, if no stream is specified, in AV_TIME_BASE units.
>   - `flags`: Flags which select direction and seeking mode.
> - `get_duration` Get movie duration in AV_TIME_BASE units.

I have tried running a command like this:

```sh
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i 'movie=filename=myvid.mp4' -codec:v libx264 -an -f mpegts - > /dev/null
```

Then I press `c` and enter the command `all -1 seek 0|3|0`, but no matter which combination I try, I get back the same error `Command reply for stream 0: ret:-78 res:`

I've also tried this command, but it gives the same error when trying to seek:

```sh
ffmpeg -i myvid.mp4 -codec:v libx264 -an -f mpegts - > /dev/null
```

There is very little information about the seek operation on the internet, but I managed to find this: http://ffmpeg.org/pipermail/ffmpeg-devel/2013-September/148070.html

Here he says that:

> the "lavfi" demuxer has its own private filtergraph and provides no
> means (that i know of) to inject command from the outside of this
> filtergraph into it.

So all this indicates that may or may not be possible to seek on a running ffmpeg instance. At least those who may have succeeded with it have kept how to do it to themselves.

Comment: Thanks. Though not a real solution to my problem, this is probably the best answer I'll get, it certainly shows effort.

Answer (score 0):

for those who want to send a filter argument

first as in [docs](https://ffmpeg.org/ffplay-all.html#toc-Changing-options-at-runtime-with-a-command) to get a particular filter commands do :

```
ffmpeg -h filter=filtername
```

**Note** : only commands marked with T will work at runtime .

next `press c` then :

```
all -1 your_command value
```

Answer (score -3):

If you hit a '?' while ffmpeg is running, you'll get all available options.

As of my locally installed version:

```
key    function
?      show this help
+      increase verbosity
-      decrease verbosity
c      Send command to first matching filter supporting it
C      Send/Que command to all matching filters
D      cycle through available debug modes
h      dump packets/hex press to cycle through the 3 states
q      quit
s      Show QP histogram
```

so basically, no.

Comment: Thanks, I know and that is why I already mentioned this in my question. It's the 'c' command where I am not sure what is possible.

Comment: maybe ask on the ffmpeg-user ML (or examine the source <sigh>)

Comment: :) Yes, that would be my next step. Thanks.